# What image of Krishna should we meditate upon?

Tags: krishna, bhakti

Since we have not seen Krishna (or Shiva or for that matter any other God) with our eyes, what image of him should be meditate upon or remember ?

Is there any description of Krishna mentioned in scripture on which we can meditate upon ?

Comment: That described in dhyanamantras

Comment: @AnubrataBit Where can I find dhyanmantras ?

Comment: It is not necessary for us to see Gods with our own eyes to be able to meditate .. Dhyana Slokas (Mantras) are mentioned in scriptures specifically for that purpose. They contain adequate description of the deity's looks. Dhyana Slokas are found in various scriptures like Puranas, Tantras. Dhyana Sloka literally means meditative verse @river

Comment: Refer to meditation lectures of Swami Mukundananda  on Youtube for Roop-Dhyanam.He is the Senior Disciple of HH Jagadguru Kripalu Maharaj Ji who specializes in Gaudiya Vaishnavism.