# Can anyone share Dhyanmantra for Krishna?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, mantras, bhakti, meditation

[Since we have not seen Krishna](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/53146/23709) ,I want to know What image of Krishna should we mediate upon.
So,I want to know [Dhaynmantra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/53146/what-image-of-krishna-should-we-meditate-upon#comment164009_53146)[/DhyanSholaka](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/53146/what-image-of-krishna-should-we-meditate-upon#comment164026_53146) for Krishna.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:

- This is primary version of answer, under construction and will be updated with more information

All of these are taken from the *Vṛhattantrasāra*

For the 10-lettered mantra

> Remember *Govinda* situated in the beautiful *Vṛndāvana* surrounded by a thousand *gopī*s. These *gopī*s are sending bees in the form of their glances to savour the nectar of beauty oozing from that flower which is His body. All of them are afflicted with the arrows of *Kāma* & are eager to hug Him. Pearl necklaces shine over their large breasts whose weight which causes them to bow down a little. Their hair-braids & clothes are disheveled & their speech is stuttering due to intoxication. Their lips shine due to the reflection of their teeth. Being proud of their feelings, they are trying to attract Him by various postures & mannerisms. The colour of His body is like that of a full-bloomed blue lotus, His body is as resplendent as the moon, He is adorned with peacock feathers. His chest is adorned with the *śrīvatsa* symbol, He bears the *Kaustubha* gem, He wears a beautiful yellow garment. He is adorned by the lotuses in form of the eyes of the *gopī*s & is surrounded by cattle & *gopa*s. Worship that *Govinda* who is adorned with divine ornaments & is playing the flute with His hands.

[image]
*Sketch of a Pāla era Kṛṣṇa idol recently unearthed from Simraungaṛh, the ancient capital of Mithilā, currently situated in Nepāla, matching the characteristics as described before*

For the 20-lettered mantra

> In the city of *Dvārāvatī* lies a bejeweled *maṇḍapa* surrounded by many *kaplavṛkṣa*s (celestial wish-fulfulling trees) & residential homes that shine like a thousand suns. Its pillars, doors, gateways & walls are made up of precious stones that shine like fire. Within this *maṇḍapa* lies a baldaquin decorated with pearl-strings & garlands of full-bloomed flowers. This *maṇḍapa* is situated under a divine tree in midst of an island of *padmarāga* (a kind of sapphire) within an artificial stream containing precious stones. It is being illuminated in all directions by bejeweled lamp-stands. In this *maṇḍapa* lies a lotus-shaped bejeweled throne that is as red as the rising sun.  Meditate upon *Acutya* seated upon it, whose complexion is like that of burnished gold. His brightness appears like that of crores of moons, suns & lighting bolts which have appeared simultaneously. He is handsome, his every limb is beautiful, he is bedecked with all sorts of ornaments. He wears a yellow garment, his arms are resplendent with the discus, conchshell, mace & lotus. He is being anointed by the stream of water containing precious stones poured over His head by the hands of *Rukmiṇī* & *Satyabhāmā*, who stand to His left & right respectively. They are being supplied with the pots by *Nāgnajitī* & *Sunandā* respectively. *Mitravindā* & the good *Lakṣmaṇā* are situated to their right & left respectively, filling up the pots with the water containing precious stones from the artificial stream. They are being instructed by *Jāmbavatī* & *Suśīlā* situated in the right & lefft respectively. Surrounding them from behind stand the 16000 junior wives with golden pots filled with water & precious stones in their hands. Surrounding them stand the 8 *nidhi*s who are filling the earth with treasures. Surrounding them are standing the *Vṛṣṇi*s. They are in turn surrounded by the *sura*s.

Answer (score 2):

[Hindupedia](https://www.hindupedia.com/en/Dhyana_Slokams_for_different_Gods) gives Dhyana Shlokas/Mantras for a variety of deities.

For Shri Krishna (actually for Bala Krishna or child Krishna) we get the following:

> Lord Krishna
>
> Balam neelambhudhabham navamani vilasadkinkini jalabadham,
> Sronijangandayugmam vipularuru nakha prollasad ganda bhoosham,
> Phullambhojavakthram hatha sakata marut poothanadhyam prasannam,
> Govindam vandhithendradhya varamamumpoojayedh vasaradhou.
>
> I pray daily morning to Him who is being saluted by Indra and other
> devas, Who is a child with the blue colour of the clouds, who ties on
> his leg and hips, The jingling belt made of the nine precious gems,
> who wears a chain, With a tiger’s claw hanging on it, who has a face
> like a fully opened lotus flower, Who killed asuras like Sakata,
> Trunavartha, and Poothana laughingly, And who is the cowherd who
> protects all beings.

But this is not the only such Dhyana Shloka for Krishna. There are many more depending on the Prayogas done or Krishna mantras which are being practiced. I will try to add some more here later.

Answer (score 1):

हरे कृष्ण हरे कृष्ण , कृष्ण कृष्ण हरे हरे |
हरे राम हरे राम , राम राम हरे हरे ||

The mantra can be found in its origin in the Kali-Santarana Upanishad, a Vaishnav Upanishad of the Krishna Yajurveda

“The sixteen words- Hare Krishna, Hare Krishna, Krishna Krishna, Hare Hare Hare Rama, Hare Rama, Rama Rama, Hare Hare- are especially meant for counteracting the contaminations of Kali. To save oneself from the contamination of Kali, there is no alternative in all the Vedas except the chanting of these sixteen words.”~Kali-santarana Upanishad